# List implementation with shared_ptr using C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, pointers

I wrote list, which I think is more elaborate than usual.  I would like to ask you for some tips, criticisms, and general feedback about my code.

```
#ifndef _LIST_HPP
#define _LIST_HPP
#include<memory>
#include<iostream>
#include<cassert>

template<typename T>
class List{
    private:
        struct Node{
            std::shared_ptr<Node> next;
            T value;

            Node():next(nullptr){};
            Node(T item,std::shared_ptr<Node> node):value(item),next(node){};
            Node(T item):value(item),next(nullptr){};
        };

        std::shared_ptr<Node> head;   //head is also header node as the first node of the list 
        std::shared_ptr<Node> tail;   // but it have no element, is not considered to be an element
        std::shared_ptr<Node> curr;   // of the list
        size_t size;

        void deepCopy(const List<T>& l){
            if(this!=&l){
                size=l.size;
                curr=tail=head=l.head;
                auto l_curr=l.curr;
                auto this_curr=curr;
                l_curr=l_curr->next; //head have any element in so we must go to next
                while(l_curr->next){
                    this_curr=this_curr->next;
                    this_curr->value=l_curr->value;
                    l_curr=l_curr->next;
                    if(l_curr->next)this_curr->next=std::make_shared<Node>();
                }
                    this_curr->value=l_curr->value;//assign last element 
            }
        }

        void clear(){
            moveToStart();
            while(curr->next){
                remove();
            }
        }

    public:
        List():size(0),head(std::make_shared<Node>()),curr(tail),tail(head){};
        List(const List<T>& l){deepCopy(l);}
        List(List<T>&&);
        ~List(){clear();};
        List<T>& operator=(const List<T>& l);
        List<T>& operator=(List<T>&&);

        void insert(T);
        void append(T);
        T remove();
        void moveToStart(){curr=head;}
        void moveToEnd(){curr=tail;}
        void goNext();
        int lenght(){return size;}
        void prev(){ if(curr->next)curr=curr->next;}
        T getValue()const;
        int getPosition();
        void moveToPos(int pos);
        template <typename U>friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,const List<U>&); 
};


template<typename T>
List<T>::List(List<T>&& l){
    deepCopy(l);
    l.clear();
}

template<typename T>
List<T>& List<T>::operator=(const List<T>& l){
    deepCopy(l);
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
List<T>& List<T>::operator=(List<T>&& l){
    deepCopy(l);
    l.clear();
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::insert(T item){
    curr->next=std::make_shared<Node>(item,curr->next);
    if(tail==curr) tail=curr->next;
    ++size;
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::append(T item){
    tail->next=std::make_shared<Node>(item);
    tail=tail->next;
    ++size;
}

template<typename T>
T List<T>::remove(){
    assert(curr->next!=nullptr);
    T it=curr->next->value;
    if(tail=curr->next) tail=curr;
    curr->next=curr->next->next;
    --size;
    return it;
}

template<typename T>
int List<T>::getPosition(){
    auto temp=head.get();
    int i=0;
    for(i;temp!=curr.get();++i)
        temp=temp->next.get();
    return i;
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::moveToPos(int pos){
    if(pos>=size) return;
    auto temp=head.get();
    int i=0;
    while(i<pos-1){
        temp=temp->next.get();
        ++i;
    }
    curr=temp->next;
}

template<typename T>
T List<T>::getValue()const{
    assert(curr->next!=nullptr);
    return curr->next->value;
}

template<typename U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const List<U>& l){
    auto temp=l.head.get();
    temp=temp->next.get();
    while(temp){
        os<<temp->value<<std::endl;
        temp=temp->next.get();
    }
    return os;
}
#endif

//and some test 


#include<ostream>
#include"list.hpp"

typedef int T;

bool  checkRemove(List<T>&);
bool checkGoNextAndPrev(List<T>&);
bool checkPos(List<T>&);
void insert(List<T>&);
void append(List<T>&);
bool checkCopy(List<T>&);

int main(){
    List<T> l;
    insert(l);
   // append(l);
    std::cout<<std::boolalpha;
    std::cout<<"remove "<<checkRemove(l)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"pos "<<checkPos(l)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"checkGoNextAndPrev "<<checkGoNextAndPrev(l)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<l;
    l.moveToStart();
    std::cout<<"copy "<<checkCopy(l);

}

bool  checkRemove(List<T>& l ){
    int len=l.lenght();
    l.remove();
    return len-1==l.lenght();
}

bool checkGoNextAndPrev(List<T>& l){
    l.prev();
    l.prev();
    return 2==l.getPosition();
}

bool checkPos(List<T>& l){
    l.moveToPos(2);
    bool boo=(2==l.getPosition());
    l.moveToStart();
    return boo;
}
void insert(List<T>& l){
    for(int i=1;i<25;++i){
        l.insert(i);
    }
}

void append(List<T>& l){
    for(int i=1;i<25;++i){
        l.append(i);
    }
}

bool checkCopy(List<T>& l){
    List<T> l2(l);
    bool copyConstr=(l2.lenght()==l.lenght());
    List<T> l3;
    l3=l;
    std::cout<<l3;
    bool copyOperator=(l3.lenght()==l.lenght());
    List<T> l4;
    l4=std::move(l);
    bool moveOperator=(l4.lenght()!=l.lenght());
    return moveOperator&&copyOperator&&copyConstr;
}
```

Comment: I am so sorry. I will never do it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Move assignment and constructor too expensive

Whenever I see `Type(Type &&);`, I expect that operation to be cheaper than `Type(const Type&)`. However, in your case, it's far too expensive. You're creating a copy of something that's going to be "moved from" either way. In your move constructor, you should simply take ownership of the `shared_ptr`s:

```
template<typename T>
List<T>::List(List<T>&& l){
    head.swap(l.head);
    tail.swap(l.tail);
    curr.swap(l.curr);
}

template<typename T>
List<T>& List<T>::operator=(List<T>&& l){
    head.swap(l.head);
    tail.swap(l.tail);
    curr.swap(l.curr);
    return *this;
}
```

## Let them clear themselves

Why no `clear` call in the operator/constructor above? Because `clear` should be also trivial:

```
void clear(){
    curr = tail = head = std::make_shared<Node>();
}
```

After all, your list is a forward-list. Every node only points to the next one, and at the moment all three `head`, `tail` and `curr` go out of scope, the items will be deleted (unless you accidentally added a loop somewhere).

## No overhead for empty objects

You have an "empty" node at the end of your list. This is troublesome due to two limitations:

1. all your `List<T>`s need to allocate, even if they never get used
2. one cannot use `List<T>` with types that don't support default construction

## Don't call things by wrong names

`deepCopy` **does not create a deep copy**. Instead, it does overwrite a list with its own (later) values and has *two* `List<T>` manage the same contents. That's due to your `head = l.head` line.

You could use `insert` here instead. If you provided an iterator interface, you could simply use

```
clear();    

for(const auto & value : otherList){
   this->append(value);
}
```

but that's left as an exercise.

## Don't use `typedef int T`

Single-letter type variables are used in template declarations, but never with `typedef`. This looks like a bunch of declared template functions:

```
bool checkRemove(List<T>&);
bool checkGoNextAndPrev(List<T>&);
bool checkPos(List<T>&);
void insert(List<T>&);
void append(List<T>&);
bool checkCopy(List<T>&);
```

but it isn't. Use `typedef int my_test_type` or something else with a better name.

## Documentation, documentation, documentation

Your class has no documentation, except for `head`, `curr` and `tail`, and I wouldn't count those three lines as actual documentation. I'm not talking about implementers documentation, e.g.

```
template<typename T>
List<T>::List(List<T>&& other){
    // Due to the nature of shared_ptr, we can swap
    // our current head, tail and curr with the 
    // @c other values. Swapping is noexcept. The @c other
    // list will be empty.
    head.swap(other.head);
    tail.swap(other.tail);
    curr.swap(other.curr);
}
```

but users:

```
// Advances the internal position to the next item. 
// If there is no item, it will stay on the last item.
//
// @seealso getPosition(), setPosition()
void List<T>::goNext();
```

By the way, you never implemented `goNext()`.

## Summary

Don't make the move operations more expensive than the non-move ones, use features that you already have at hand (`shared_ptr::~shared_ptr`), don't lie to yourself (`deepCopy`), don't limit your class with arbitrary constraints (unless there's a reason), add documentation, and test more thoroughly.

It's good that you have tests, but they didn't catch the bug in `deepCopy`.